# Reading file in 2d array

Tags: c++, file

I am trying in this function to read data from csv file in 2d array but when print the array the output is zero, What is the issue?
The file has 5 rows and 500 columns

```
void readFilesToReadings() {
int row = 5;
int col = 10;

int myArray[row][col];
string fileName, BasefileName = "C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/frac/Z500.csv"
//Opening the file
ifstream inputfile(fileName);

if (!inputfile.is_open()) 
cout<<"Error opening file" ;

//Defining the loop for getting input from the file

for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) //Outer loop for rows
{
    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) //inner loop for columns
    {
      inputfile >> myArray[r][c];  //Take input from file and put into myArray
    }
}

for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
    {
        cout << myArray[r][c] << "\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

}
```

Update1:
this is the output for the user20716902  answer

[image]

Comment: Please search the internet before posting to StackOverflow.  Try this:  "C++ read file 2d array".  There are already a plethora of questions and and answers related to this topic.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  Please post the results of your debugging session, in text.  Indicate which statement is causing the issue, actual values of variables and expected values of variables.

Comment: What Thomas said, but also its unclear to me why you have your outer loop start at 1 since it forces you to do `i - 1` everwhere else... (and you did do that for your inner loop so theyre inconsistent with each other)

Comment: Your indentation seems to indicate you expect both statement under the inner for to be in the inner loop but that is *not* the case. Since you did not use {} only the first one is. the cout one is outside the inner loop.

Comment: check the file opened. check that each read operation worked.

Comment: I update my code and the output is Error opening file!

Comment: You have edited the shown code, probably reacting to a comment. This implies that it never was a [mre]. It still is not. Please [edit] to provide one.

Comment: If you get the error which tells you about problems opening the file, but your program still goes on trying to read it.... what do you expect?

Comment: After the edit of the question, I keep my close-vote up. Note that I now consider it for the reason "Not reproducable", because after the mentioned error it is obvious that reading will fail. The expectation that it would not fail is not reproducable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fixed code, you were only setting BasefileName (which was never used, and fileName was not set, so of course your file open failed. (I've tested with my own csv and they now works):

```
void readFilesToReadings() {
   const int row = 5;
   const int col = 10;

   int myArray[row][col];
   string fileName = "C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/frac/Z500.csv";
   
   //Opening the file
   ifstream inputfile(fileName);

   if (!inputfile.is_open())
   {
      cout << "Error opening file";
   }
   else {

      //Defining the loop for getting input from the file

      for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) //Outer loop for rows
      {
          for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) //inner loop for columns
          {
             inputfile >> myArray[r][c];  //Take input from file and put into myArray
          }
      }

      for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
      {
          for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
          {
              cout << myArray[r][c] << "\t";
          }
          cout << endl;
      }
   }
```

}

Comment: Yes, and the new code has more issues than before, BasefileName is not even used and fileName is never set

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the current question

Comment: Could you skip the reading attempt after a failure/erroroutput? That would cover the version which includes the comment that the error message is output and **then** reading fails.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch I've updated the answer, it will now handle the scenario where the file open fails

Comment: Thanks all. But now I can read just the first value in csv file and all the other are unreadable why ?

Comment: I am using Win10 and use this commands for run >g++ progname.cpp    and then   a

Comment: I would suggest that the issue is with how you have formatted the csv file. As the csv test file that I created had each number seperated by a single tab character for the columns, and a carriage return for each row. If your csv has commas, quotes etc... this could be the source of your issue.

Comment: I used .TXT and the same just the first value like the file and all the other are uncorrect !!

Comment: Perhaps you can provide an example of the .txt file that you are having issues with, maybe a screenhot from notepad++ ? In notepad++ you can use the option View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters. This will allow us to see how your csv is actually formatted and what seperators you have used.

Answer (score 0):

Reading stuff from file is not difficult in C++, but there is a pattern you should follow. It is easiest to make yourself a little function to implement this pattern.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T, size_t ROWS, size_t COLUMNS>
bool load_readings_from_file( 
    const std::string & filename, 
    T (&array)[ROWS][COLUMNS], 
    char delimiter = ',' )
{
    std::ifstream f( filename );
    for (size_t row = 0;  row < ROWS;  row++)
    {
        for (size_t column = 0;  column < COLUMNS;  column++)
        {
            f >> std::ws;
            if (f.peek() == delimiter) f.get();
            f >> array[row][column];
        }
    }
    return (bool)f;
}
```

I have used templates so you can pass any size array you want to it, but you could easily hardcode the array type (size) in the global namespace if you want.

```
using ReadingsArrayType = int[5][10];

bool load_readings_from_file(
    const std::string & filename,
    ReadingsArrayType array,
    char delimiter = ',' )
{
    ...
}
```

Either way, using it to fill an array from file is about as easy as it looks:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int rows = 5;
    constexpr int cols = 10;
    
    int myReadingsArray[rows][cols];
    
    if (!load_readings_from_file( "C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/frac/Z500.csv", myReadingsArray ))
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not load file!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Print the matrix
    for (int r = 0;  r < rows;  r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0;  c < cols;  c++)
        {
            std::cout << myReadingsArray[r][c] << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

(Again, if you use the array type directly:

```
int main()
{
    ReadingsArrayType myReadingsArray;

    if (!load_readings_from_file( ... )) ...
```

As you can see it is much less clear that `myReadingsArray` is, in fact, an array... So I personally tend to avoid this kind of type aliasing.)

Finally, you should generally avoid using absolute paths for your filenames. Put the data in the same directory as your executable, or a subdirectory of it. Better yet, let the user supply a filename:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage:\n  myprog FILENAME\n";
        return 1;
    }

    const char * filename = argv[1];

    int myReadingsArray[5][10];

    if (!load_readings_from_file( filename, myReadingsArray )) ...
```

Creating functions to do stuff is just one step away from applying the full power of C++ to serialize objects for you. You’ll get to that a little later.